# Get other columns when asking for nlargest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `DataFrame` `outputDF` that looks like this:

```
                      Range      Date1      Date2  maxDD
0     11/01/2016:07/20/2017 2017-02-22 2017-06-27   0.29
1     11/02/2016:07/21/2017 2017-02-22 2017-06-27   0.29
2     11/03/2016:07/24/2017 2017-02-22 2017-06-27   0.29
3     11/04/2016:07/25/2017 2017-02-22 2017-06-27   0.29
4     11/07/2016:07/26/2017 2017-02-22 2017-06-27   0.29
...
```

When I ask for `nlargest`

```
fiveLargestDD = outputDF['maxDD'].nlargest(n=5)
```

I just get one column - `maxDD`. How do I ask to return all the `columns` except the index?

Answer (score 2):

Returns all the columns:

```
outputDF.nlargest(5, 'maxDD')
```

Comment: Yeah, LOL, this syntax is the correct one. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try,

```
df.loc[fiveLargestDD.index, :]
```